# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I am making a shop and using an input to get results, now I have the AJAX that calls the PHP script and it calls it fine, but I get an error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064

**NOTE**: The error line is the `$query->execute(array(':input'=>$input))` line

here's the AJAX script ( + HTML calling the function )

```
                     <input type="text" name="search_item" onkeyup="showItems(this.value)" id="search_item">
                     <script>
                        function showItems(str) {
                            if (str.length == 0) { 

                            } else {
                                var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                                    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                                        document.getElementById("items").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                                    }
                                };
                                xmlhttp.open("GET", "searchScript.php?iName=" + str, true);
                                xmlhttp.send();
                            }
                        }
                    </script>
```

and here's the called PHP:

```
    $input = $_REQUEST["iName"];
    $input = "%".$input."%"; 
$dsn = 'mysql:host=xxx.com;dbname=dbNameHidden;charset=utf8mb4';
$username = 'hidden';
$password = 'hidden';

try{
    // connect to mysql
    $con = new PDO($dsn,$username,$password);
    $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo 'Not Connected '.$ex->getMessage();
}
$query = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM store AS s INNER JOIN product_pictures AS pp ON s.product_id = pp.id INNER JOIN product_name AS pn ON s.product_id = pn.id WHERE product_name LIKE %:input% LIMIT 9 ");
$query->execute(array(':input' => $input));
$items = $query->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Results in `LIKE %'something'%` which is not correct.  Add `%` to the variable not the query.

Comment: You can't put wildcards on the outside of your binding. Put it around your input before you pass it in.

Comment: I still get an error

Comment: Im editing the `PHP` code to the updated one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the wildcards to the parameter:

```
$query = $con->prepare("SELECT ... WHERE product_name LIKE :input LIMIT 9 ");
$query->execute(array(':input' => '%' . $input. '%'));
```

That way the wildcards are contained in the value, essentially making the query like this:

```
SELECT .... WHERE product_name LIKE '%name%'
```

Comment: ohh there, okay im trying

Comment: Great - if you believe this is the best solution, please [accept answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). For more information, see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: oh yes i had to wait a couple of minutes and then i just forgot

Answer (score 0):

Your query results in `LIKE %'something'%` which is not correct. Add `%` to the variable not the query. You want something like:

```
$input = "%$input%";

$query = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM store AS s 
                        INNER JOIN product_pictures AS pp ON s.product_id = pp.id
                        INNER JOIN product_name AS pn ON s.product_id = pn.id
                        WHERE product_name LIKE :input LIMIT 9 ");
$query->execute(array(':input' => $input));
```